# Dissolving in ArcMap gives "Invalid Topology [Duplicate Segment.]"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve

I am attempting to use the dissolve tool on a shapefile, but it fails with the error:

ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Invalid Topology [Duplicate segment.]

I tried checking and repairing geometry until no more geometry errors exist. I also tried the fix topology error tool, but the topology edit tool says that no topology exists. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: The `Duplicate segment` warning may be the key. Have you tried running [Find Identical](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/heLP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001700000054000000)? (Repair Geometry doesn't look for duplicate polygons/lines.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I found many duplicate rows, so I ran delete identical and got rid of them. However, the dissolve tool still failed with the same error.

Comment: Hmm. [Try using a feature class in a geodatabase instead of a shapefile?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/16688/15768)

Comment: Importing into a GDB worked! Thanks so much for the guidance. Feel free to make an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Thank you -- I answered it more or less the same as I commented, just in case (a) both approaches were necessary to resolve it and (b) it helps somebody with a similar problem in future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is running [Find Identical](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/heLP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001700000054000000), since the error specifies "Duplicate Segment" -- Repair Geometry doesn't look for identical features, just for invalid geometries.

Sometimes ArcMap just doesn't like shapefiles as well as feature classes in a geodatabase, so [converting to a GDB and then trying again is another possible solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16684/why-is-the-dissolve-tool-not-working/16688#16688).